# android intent putExtra Parsefile

Tags: android, android-intent, parse-platform

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("title", (meal.getTitle()));


                /*intent.putExtra("photo",
                        (meal.getParseFile("photo")));*/


                mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

As you can see , I am trying to send a parsefile (returns photo file to be exact) with put extra to show it on another .xml file , anyway the problem is of course  that I can't use putExtra(String) like the getTitle , and on the SingItemView.class :

```
String title , b;
Meal meal = new Meal();
        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get the results of rank
        title = i.getStringExtra("title");
        b = i.getStringExtra("photo");
        // Load the results into the TextViews

        // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
        txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        txtrank.setText(title);
        ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon1);
        ParseFile photoFile = meal.getParseFile("photo");
        if (photoFile != null) {
            mealImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
            mealImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    // nothing to do
                }
            });
```

I set the image into the praseimageview in the xml and did tested out , but I didn't get the expected result (image from putextra on the first activity error) , and I think the b= i.get......photo"); doesn't really work with parsefile.

my question is , what kind of putextra to use with ParseFile , and how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you want to avoid putting large objects into Bundles unnecessarily.
I'd say a much more efficient, and simple solution would be to place the image URL into the Intent, and retrieve it from the single image Activity.

```
public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "image";
...
i.putStringExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, photoFile.getUrl());
```

And in your SingleItemView.java

```
String imageUrl = i.getStringExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE);
```

You can then use this image URL to load the image using **Picasso** for example:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

More information on Picasso can be found [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: will this work since I am using parse.com and the image is inside of a class

Comment: Yes, you can load the image with the URL from wherever. You don't need ParseImageView

Comment: thanks for your answer  , i used getparsefile.geturl() it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get the byte[] of the ParseFile, store the bytes in a Bundle or Intent, which of course can be retrieved from the called Activity/Fragment.

Example:

```
ParseFile mFile = meal.getParseFile("photo"); 
final byte[] mImageData = mFile.getData();
```

the byte array can now be stored in intent or bundle and passed across application components. You can convert byte[] back to an image by

```
final Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mImageData, 0, mImageData.length);
```

getData() on ParseFile blocks the mainthread, so you might want to do it in the background using GetDataInBackground, like you are already using in your question above.  You can find more information at

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#files